# Delphi - Is there a way to hide/organize Components in DESIGN mode

Tags: delphi, components

In Delphi 2010...
I am building a reasonably complex application. There are all kinds of non-visual VCL based components, such as TTable, TQuery, etc.  I know I can put Data oriented components into a datamodule, so in design time, they don't show up on my main form.  I am looking for a way to "hide" the other non-visual components.  I know that I can hide them with GExperts, but as soon as you click on the form, they show up again. I seem to recall that there was a 'Component repository' type of component.  You dropped it on your form, and then dropped all you other components into it...  Can't find it though.

Is anyone aware of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Put your other non-visual components in the data module as well.

Comment: Didn't think that was possible, but after trying it, it works fine...  If you want to submit this as an answer, I will credit it...

Comment: Done. Glad it worked for you. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put your other non-visual components on the DataModule as well. All non-visual controls can be placed there; it's only the visual (TControl/TWinControl) components that can't be (for obvious reasons - the data module has no visual aspect at runtime).

Note that this is useful even in applications that don't access databases of any sort. You can still create a `TDataModule` to hold all of your non-visual components like image lists, file open/save dialogs, and so forth.

Comment: I put all my Reports components in a separate DataModule. Handy.

Comment: BTW, I would love to have some form of TGroup for data modules. Also, autoarrange.